# Убрать тень при нажатии на кнопку (CSS)

Tags: css, vaadin

[image: Тень от кнопки]

Использую Vaadin. Имеется Button, которую превратил (средствами CSS) в Link. Но вот проблема: при нажатии на кнопку, и (не отпуская левую кнопку мыши) отводя в сторону мышь, остается тень. Предполагаю, что надо добавлять что-то в элемент с  *:active. 
Гуглил, но ответа не нашел, или не правильно искал. Можете помочь? Заранее всем благодарен за активность!

Вот код, который есть у меня:

```css
.button-reply {
  color: #2793DB;
  padding-right: 3px;
  margin-top: -5pxt;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.button-reply:hover:after {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.button-reply:active {}
```

```html
<button class="button-reply">button</button>
```

Comment: а добавление в `:active` `background-color: transparent; ` не дает разве результатов?

Comment: :active box-shadow: 0 0  0 rgba(0,0,0,0);

Comment: @DantheHat к сожалению, нет

Answer (score 1):

```css
.button-reply {
  color: #2793DB;
  padding-right: 3px;
  margin-top: -5pxt;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.button-reply:hover:after {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.button-reply:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-reply">button</button>
```

Comment: Это совершенно не то, о чем я говорил. Мне же наоборот необходимо убрать тень, а не добавлять её

Comment: @alex, убрать тень при клике, так в вопросе или я что то не правильно понял?

Comment: ...при нажатии на кнопку, и (не отпуская левую кнопку мыши) отводя в сторону мышь, остается тень. Её и необходимо убрать. Или хотя бы закрасить под белый фон. Кстати... как вариант

Comment: @alex, у меня в примере тоже самое, посмотри, нажимаешь и отводишь ее нет)))

Comment: в Vaadin'e почему-то это не работает)

Comment: @alex, попробуй так я добавил !important